# Concurrent RPC server

Tags: c, rpc

I need to create a concurrent RPC server which is capable of handling multiple requests from client simultaneously.

Using `rpcgen` compiler in linux (which is based on sun RPC), it does not support the `-A` option which creates stubs for concurrent servers. (the `-A` option is available in solaris)

Appreciate if someone can provide some idea on this:

1. What is the way to create concurrent RPC server in linux. Some googling suggests making changes in stub, which isn't a good idea.
2. Any other RPC packages available - alternative to sun rpc.

Answer (score 3):

It's such an old post and surely you will already have solved it, but it can be helpfull to somebody else:

In the "**rpcgen**" RPC compiler provided in the GNU toolchain the corresponding option is "**`-M`**", for example:

**`rpcgen -M your_xdr_file.x`**

The change in the generated code is simple but elegant: the caller is who has to alloc the buffer where the client stub will write the response. This is the common behaviour in thread safe APIs. So will happen in the server stub, and there appears a hook in the server (called "`PROGRAMNAME_VERSION_freeresult`") where you will have the opportunity to free all the resources that you could have allocated when executing the call in the server side.

Hope it helps someone!